# SSL Requests from a different IP than Non SSL requests

Tags: https

When using tbb,every time I visit Doileak.com,it says

> Your SSL Requests come from a different IP than your Non SSL requests.
>   Your Proxy seems not to support SSL, which is dangerous as the proxy
>   can read and modify all your traffic.

And ipcheck(jondonym) also says the simillar thing.(not always but sometimes)

I thought I should use https if possible,when using tor.
Was I wrong?

Comment: Their tests are false positives and providing incorrect information, you should use HTTPS whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Your SSL Requests come from a different IP than your Non SSL requests. Your Proxy seems not to support SSL, which is dangerous as the proxy can read and modify all your traffic.

Looks to me like Doileak hasn't been designed for the use with Tor Browser. When I look at the results, it shows me 2 or more different IPs. If I check them on [atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org), they are all Tor IPs. You can also compare them with your actual IP, they'll differ.

> I thought I should use https if possible,when using tor. Was I wrong?

Yes, you should use HTTPS whenever possible (not just on Tor)